# Elastic search find total hits for a date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to find total records in my user table for a particular date, i can able to find the total hits, but cannot find a query to fetch date for a particular date.

Query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_team": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "created_date": {
            "from": "2015-01-02",
            "to": "2015-01-02"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 33,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "daily_team": {
         "doc_count": 1
      }
   }
}
```

Here "total": 33, but its for total number of records in my database. I have only 22 records from "starting date" to "2015-01-02". Could you please help me to find query for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, just removed "from" parameter from range, now i can get the size from doc_count.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_team": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "created_date": {
            "to": "2015-01-02"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```